# R - count indicators across multiple columns (like sumproduct in Excel)

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c('a','b','a','c','b','a'),
                 indicator1=c(1,0,0,0,1,1),
                 indicator2=c(0,0,0,1,0,1),
                 extra1=c(4,5,12,4,3,7),
                 extra2=c('z','z','x','y','x','x'))

id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2
a          1          0      4      z
b          0          0      5      z
a          0          0     12      x
c          0          1      4      y
b          1          0      3      x
a          1          1      7      x
```

I would like to add a new column with a count over all rows of the number of times that specific id comes up with various indicators equal to 1. e.g.:

```
id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2 countInd1 countInd2 countInd1Ind2
a          1          0      4      z      2         1           1
b          0          0      5      z      1         0           0
a          0          0     12      x      2         1           1
c          0          1      4      y      0         1           0
b          1          0      3      x      1         0           0
a          1          1      7      x      2         1           1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways. Here's one with `ave` and `within`:

```
within(df, {
  ind1ind2 <- ave(as.character(interaction(indicator1, indicator2, drop=TRUE)), 
                  id, FUN = function(x) sum(x == "1.1"))
  ind2 <- ave(indicator2, id, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 1))
  ind1 <- ave(indicator1, id, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 1))
})
#   id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2 ind1 ind2 ind1ind2
# 1  a          1          0      4      z    2    1        1
# 2  b          0          0      5      z    1    0        0
# 3  a          0          0     12      x    2    1        1
# 4  c          0          1      4      y    0    1        0
# 5  b          1          0      3      x    1    0        0
# 6  a          1          1      7      x    2    1        1
```

Here's an alternative:

```
A <- setNames(aggregate(cbind(indicator1, indicator2) ~ id, df, 
                        function(x) sum(x == 1)), c("id", "ind1", "ind2"))
B <- setNames(aggregate(interaction(indicator1, indicator2, drop = TRUE) ~ id, 
                        df, function(x) sum(x == "1.1")), c("id", "ind1ind2"))
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), list(df, A, B))
#   id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2 ind1 ind2 ind1ind2
# 1  a          1          0      4      z    2    1        1
# 2  a          0          0     12      x    2    1        1
# 3  a          1          1      7      x    2    1        1
# 4  b          0          0      5      z    1    0        0
# 5  b          1          0      3      x    1    0        0
# 6  c          0          1      4      y    0    1        0
```

---

Of course, if your data are large, you would want to explore the "data.table" package. It's also a little bit less typing than the `within` version.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, c("ind1", "ind2", "ind1ind2") := 
     list(sum(indicator1 == 1),
          sum(indicator2 == 1),
          sum(interaction(indicator1, indicator2, 
                          drop = TRUE) == "1.1")),
   by = "id"]
DT
#    id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2 ind1 ind2 ind1ind2
# 1:  a          1          0      4      z    2    1        1
# 2:  b          0          0      5      z    1    0        0
# 3:  a          0          0     12      x    2    1        1
# 4:  c          0          1      4      y    0    1        0
# 5:  b          1          0      3      x    1    0        0
# 6:  a          1          1      7      x    2    1        1
```

And, instead of `sum(interaction(...) == "1.1")`, you could also do `sum(indicator1 == 1 & indicator2 == 1)` if you feel that's more explicit. I haven't benchmarked to see which is more efficient. `interaction` is just what first came to my mind.

Comment: if `indicator1` and `indicator2` are (as they appear and appear to be named) indicators, `DT[,c('ind1','ind2','ind1ind2') := list(sum(indicator1),sum(indicator2), sum((indicator1+indicator2)>1)),by=id]` should work ( and be slighlty more efficient)

Comment: @mnel, that had occurred to me, but I didn't really want to make any assumptions about whether there might be other values in the "indicator1" and "indicator2" columns.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
get_freq1 = function(i) {sum(df[which(df$id == df[i,1]),]$indicator1)}
get_freq2 = function(i) {sum(df[which(df$id == df[i,1]),]$indicator2)} 

df = data.frame(df, countInd1 = sapply(1:nrow(df), get_freq1), countInd2 = sapply(1:nrow(df), get_freq2))
df= data.frame(df, countInd1Ind2 = ((df$countInd1 != 0) & (df$countInd2 != 0))*1)
```

You get:

```
 #  id indicator1 indicator2 extra1 extra2 countInd1 countInd2 countInd1Ind2
 #1  a          1          0      4      z         2         1             1
 #2  b          0          0      5      z         1         0             0
 #3  a          0          0     12      x         2         1             1
 #4  c          0          1      4      y         0         1             0
 #5  b          1          0      3      x         1         0             0
 #6  a          1          1      7      x         2         1             1
```